# Bulk customer upload?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer, csv

I've been searching a kind of extension to upload customers in a bulk but I didn't find anything.
Do you have any system to upload a lot of customers via csv, xls.. etc? Or there's an option that I didn't find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento has a built in system for that.
Go to `System->Import/export->Import`. For the field `Entity Type` you have the option to import customers.
The only catch is that the file must be in a specific form.
To get the columns you need go to `System->Import/export->Export` and export a sample file. Fill in that file and upload it.

Comment: thanks!!! When I tried to export customers, it appeared an error that said "Invalid entity model". But I solved it editing the file  app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php replacing  $destination = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), ‘importexport_’);  to  $destination = tempnam(Mage::getBaseDir() . ‘/var/tmp/’ , ‘importexport_’);  THANKS :)